# Playing multiple streams using libpulse

Tags: c, audio, pulseaudio

How to play multiple `audio` streams using `libpulse`. I know it is possible by summing multiple streams and playing using `libaudio` but is it possible to write multiple streams on `lib pulse` api and have PulseAudio do the summing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by implementing this.
[libpulse API](http://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/doxygen/streams.html)

**Synchronising Multiple Playback Streams**

> PulseAudio allows applications to fully synchronize multiple playback
>   streams that are connected to the same output device. That means the
>   streams will always be played back sample-by-sample synchronously. If
>   stream operations like pa_stream_cork() are issued on one of the
>   synchronized streams, they are simultaneously issued on the others. To
>   synchronize a stream to another, just pass the "master" stream as last
>   argument to pa_stream_connect_playback(). To make sure that the
>   freshly created stream doesn't start playback right-away, make sure to
>   pass PA_STREAM_START_CORKED and – after all streams have been created
>   – uncork them all with a single call to pa_stream_cork() for the
>   master stream. To make sure that a particular stream doesn't stop to
>   play when a server side buffer underrun happens on it while the other
>   synchronized streams continue playing and hence deviate, you need to
>   pass a "prebuf" pa_buffer_attr of 0 when connecting it.